# Windows Azure - Serve unknown (mp4) MIME types in Windows Azure IIS storage

Tags: c#, iis, azure, mime-types

I have a windows azure deployment (a web-role) that on request pulls in a pair of video files (mov and mp4) from azure storage into it's own local IIS storage, which I then access through the browser.

It may sound silly, but I have good reasons for doing this.

Unfortunately, I am unable to access the mp4 files. The mov are fine, but the mp4 give me "404 - File or directory not found."

I've looked into this, and it seems to be because IIS will not return unknown file types, and mp4 must fall under this category. If it was a normal IIS server I would be able to register the mp4 mime type, but I don't know how to go about this in Windows Azure.

I could RDP in and do it manually, but this would not be practical as the role is replaced frequently and would mean I would need to re-do it manually every time. It must be done through one of the config files or in code.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!!

Steven

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Can you not add custom mime type in web.config? I just ran into this link:

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/staticContent/mimeMap

The relevant web.config xml is:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".syx" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".tab" mimeType="text/plain" />
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. I *did* do a lot of googling before I asked, but I must have been using the wrong search terms!

Comment: Can this be added to the app.config instead of web.config?

Comment: Just to complement this very good answer, if you're working with react, copy this web.config to the build folder (with npm react build )in the following way (credits to Liviu Costea): https://medium.com/hackernoon/adding-web-config-to-react-projects-3eb762dbe01f

Answer (score 4):

I used suggestion from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/79eb0c22-fe78-41d6-ac57-03055610b2a8/mp4-media-files-on-azure-website?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview&prof=required:

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".mp4"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
  <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
</staticContent>
```

Answer (score 3):

To configure the mime type, create a new web.config file with this content in the video folder:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <configuration>
>   <system.webServer>
>      <staticContent>
>         <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
>         <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
>      </staticContent>
>   </system.webServer>
> </configuration>
> ```

This solution works for Azure only, the local project may no longer work. My solutions is to use "Add Config Transform" for the plublication with an empty web.config file for local project:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <configuration>
> </configuration>
> ```

And when you right click on web.config, select "Add Config Transform":

[image]

In the web.Release.config file add this into de configuration tag:

> ```
> <system.webServer xdt:Transform="Insert">
>   <staticContent>
>     <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
>     <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
>   </staticContent>
> </system.webServer>
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't add it in the same folder at first, I just updated the existing web.config and that didn't solve my issue. Now it's working great !

Answer (score 1):

For the answer to the specific question about playing videos in MIME Type of MP4.

[answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55655901/7988162)