# jsreact - GET http://localhost:8080/manifest.json 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, http-status-code-404, manifest.json

I'm trying to make my existing react application progressive by adding among other things a *manifest.json*.

However it seems that my application is unable to find my *manifest.json* file as I get the above error message and **Cannot GET /manifest.json** when I take a look at the developer tool's network tab . This is strange since my *manifest.json* is located at the root of my application, exactly where the error says it cannot find the file.

I tried several things like placing a *manifest.json* file in every directory or introducing a json-loader in my webpack configuration but nothing worked.

**Where I reference the manifest**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" >
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root" class="body"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In addition I'm using *webpack-manifest-plugin* which creates an *asset-manifest.json* file in my build directory that maps my index files.

**webpack.config**

```
//...
const ManifestPlugin = require("webpack-manifest-plugin")
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new ManifestPlugin({
            fileName: "asset-manifest.json"
        })
        //...
```

**created asset-manifest.json**

```
{
  "index.js": "index.bundle.js",
  "index.html": "index.html"
}
```

I hope you can help me

Comment: actual file is asset-manifest.json but you are try to point manifest.json?? I'm i getting wrong?

Comment: You have changed the `fileName` to `asset-manifest.json` in your webpack config, but you link to `/manifest.json` in your document. Could you try `/asset-manifest.json` in the document instead?

Comment: The asset-manifest.json is generated by the plugin with a mapping of all source file names to their corresponding output file (https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-manifest-plugin). It is **not** the manifest.json file I'm trying to refer to.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not only with manifest.json but with all json files. As it says here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29633038/3231884 , you need to setup the web.config according to the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".json" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Afterwards, you should make 'npm run build' copy it to the build folder by following these steps (credits to Liviu Costea):
https://medium.com/hackernoon/adding-web-config-to-react-projects-3eb762dbe01f

Answer (score 0):

It should be an issue of `manifest.json` file.
Please show the contents of `manifest.json` file.

Try this, In `manifest.json`
the `name` property should be in small letters and contains no spaces.

Answer (score 0):

change extension manifest
from **manifest.json** to ***manifest.txt***