# Showing videos in azurewebsites using the video tag, files is not loading

Tags: html, video, azure

I am experiencing a strange problem using the html5 video tag.
When running the site locally it loads the video but when publishing it to azurewebsites it no longer loads it.

Here is the link: *edit- no longer needed*

I have checked the folders by ftp on azure and the video is there.

Can't find any info if there are some permission issues with azure.

The video is an MP4.

Anyone know what this could be?

Comment: More than likely it seems an issue with Mime type not configured properly. Please check if that's not the case. See these thread for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151819/unable-to-host-mp4-files-on-azure-web-site & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273607/windows-azure-serve-unknown-mp4-mime-types-in-windows-azure-iis-storage.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I added the mime mapping to my web.config and it started working.

Comment: Awesome! I'm just going to mark this question as duplicate of the 1st link.