# File published to successfully to Azure web site can't be found?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I have an Azure shared web site.  I publish my web site using Visual Studio 2013 and the operation succeeds, yet certain files are reported by the browser as missing while others are fine.  The files that end up in the missing category are all binary data files for a game.  All the "normal" web files (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.) appear to be fine.  Is there some kind of special steps I need to take to publish binary data to an Azure web site?

Note, from within Visual Studio 2013 I tried to publish individually one of the missing files by using the Publish Single File option.  The publish operation succeeds, but still, the browser can't find the file when it tries to load it.  Note, I don't think it's a file size issue because several of the binary data files are only around 3 MB in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue, FTP into your website and upload the following Web.config file which will set the correct MIME types. If you already have a Web.config file in place, just add the below to the appropriate section. Replacing .json and application/json with the file you're trying to load.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
     </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing in this instance you haven't configured the mimeTypes for these files, if they are to be served through the server.  There's a quick [explanation](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2010/05/13/3gp-files-not-served-by-iis.aspx) and an [appropriate resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273607/windows-azure-serve-unknown-mp4-mime-types-in-windows-azure-iis-storage) to your problem.

HTH