# ReactJs Application returning 404 Not Found for a static file

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service, create-react-app

I have a ReactJs application that was created using react-create-app. I have deployed my application to an Azure App Service Plan (sku F1).

When running the application in local host the background video runs as expected. However, after deployment I find that the server is returning a 404 not found for my .mp4 file (and thereby not loading the background video as expected).

[Debug Console in browser showing 404 on load of .mp4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnNb4.png)

Request General Info:

```
Request URL: https://abouthorusrm.azurewebsites.net/static/media/typing.203864c7a88151d96941.mp4
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 13.89.172.5:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Request Headers:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: ARRAffinity=f4edef8e8ae33d792aa347f6380e743b9805a4dd08725995c30ae1f829052383;ARRAffinitySameSite=f4edef8e8ae33d792aa347f6380e743b9805a4dd08725995c30ae1f829052383
Host: abouthorusrm.azurewebsites.net
Range: bytes=0-
Referer: https://abouthorusrm.azurewebsites.net/
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Brave";v="115", "Chromium";v="115"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: video
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Gpc: 1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Response Headers:

```
Content-Length:103
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Sun, 06 Aug 2023 21:41:53 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

I am expecting this file to load and display the .mp4 file as a background of my web app.

The file that is returning 404 is located in the optimized build folder of my react app at the following path:

build/static/media/typing.203864c7a88151d96941.mp4

And I have verified (via Kudu) that the file with the same case-sensitive naming is located on the server at the following path:

C:\home\site\wwwroot\static\media\typing.203864c7a88151d96941.mp4

[Screenshot of Web Server filesystem in kudu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXrpi.png)

I have attempted to add a web.config file to the server to allow .mp4 mime types with the following content:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
         <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml">
         </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This, however, did not resolve the issue at hand.

Strangely enough, there is an .svg file that is being referenced from this same directory that renders without issue.

[Debug Console in browser showing successful load of .svg in same directory as .mp4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm4E5.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with the same Approach that which you have provided and got the same error.

[image]

I have modified the code as below.
In App.js file added the source for .mp4.

**App.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Welcome to React MP4 App</h1>
      <video controls autoPlay loop className="background-video">
        <source src="/sample-mp4-file-small.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
      <p>This is a sample React app with an MP4 video.</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**App.css:**

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

**Local:**

[image]

- I have deployed React app to azure app service successfully.

[image]

- File structure path in KUDU:

[image]

[image]

**Output:**
[image]

Further any clarification required refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6274043/21525734) link.